# How to Convert special chars with their entity names (like & with &amp;) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small requirement, have `JSON` data and I would like to convert all `specialChars` with `escapeChars`,
I tried with following code but it throws an error like `Object doesn't support property or method 'split'`, please share me your ideas.

```
function applyEscapeChars()
                {                              
                            var str = { "aaData": ["dummy < data","ampersand&aaa","2015-02-16","2015-02-16",470.5,"xyz",1,0,"","Error: 1 Invalid format/sample","---"]}                            
                            var specialChars = new Array();
                                specialChars[0] = "&";
                                specialChars[1] = "\"";
                                specialChars[2] = "'";
                                specialChars[3] = "<";
                                specialChars[4] = ">";
                                var escapeChars = new Array();
                                escapeChars[0] = "&amp;";
                                escapeChars[1] = "&quot;";
                                escapeChars[2] = "&apos;";
                                escapeChars[3] = "&lt;";
                                escapeChars[4] = "&gt;";

                                for (var i =0; i < specialChars.length; i++ )
                                {                             
                                         str = JSON.stringify(str ).split(specialChars[i]).join(escapeChars[i]);                                             
                                }
                                //alert(str);

                                return str;

                }
```

Now everything is working fine except `less than symbol(<)`

Comment: `str` is not  a string its an object, you can probably convert it to a string modify it then convert it back to an object.

Comment: Why don't you try using `encodeURIComponent()` method in JavaScript?

Comment: If you want to use split then you can write JSON.stringify(str).split()

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok for you to let the browser do the html encoding?

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
  //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

It's taken from [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)